# Trying to Bind the gridview but after binding data and rows both disappear

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I' m trying to bind a gridview using Ajax jquery.while I saw the data is bind with gridview and shown in the browser but after completion of debugging .all data that fill up the rows goes disappear.Trying to find out the issue but after execution of   $("#THistory").click(function () { this function the debugger goes to Page_Load method
Ajax part

```
 <%--GridView Populate--%> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $("#THistory").click(function () {           
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TDC.aspx/GetCustomers",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var customers = xml.find("Table");
                var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("REVISION").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("P_GROUP").text());
                    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
     <%--GridView Populate--%>
```

.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                    this.BindDummyRow();
            }
        }
 private void BindDummyRow()
    {
        DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
        dummy.Columns.Add("REVISION");
        dummy.Columns.Add("P_GROUP");
        dummy.Rows.Add();
        gvCustomers.DataSource = dummy;
        gvCustomers.DataBind();
        //gvCustomers.Visible = false;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers()
    {
        string query = "SELECT REVISION, P_GROUP from tdc_product1 ";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }
    private static DataSet GetData(OracleCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: open you browser console and check for errors, tell us what you see

Comment: Error appear without debugging .Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.

Comment: @Ferus7Actually when data is binded with gridview and visible on browser debugger went to Page_Load method further and page becomes blank.any ways to prevent further going to page load method